# Can't figure out the root cause of out of resources error

Tags: resources, messaging, qos, data-distribution-service

I have an application using **RTI DDS** using `dynamic data` to set my messages.

When I try to send a string that was `300kb` in a file I get the following error code:

```
com.rti.dds.infrastructure.RETCODE_OUT_OF_RESOURCES
    at com.rti.dds.util.Utilities.rethrow(Unknown Source) ~[nddsjava.jar:?]
    at com.rti.dds.infrastructure.RETCODE_ERROR.check_return_codeI(Unknown Source) ~[nddsjava.jar:?]
    at com.rti.dds.dynamicdata.DynamicData.set_string(Unknown Source) ~[nddsjava.jar:?]
```

I have searched on their forum and tried all changes I can think of to my QOS policy file to avoid this error, of which none have worked.

I figured the best way to now go about solving this problem is getting to the root cause of the problem, however I have hit a wall and can't figure out if it is OS related, a memory leak, or what.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing me this issue with RTI DDS?

Comment: When you invoked [`DynamicData()`](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.0/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1dynamicdata_1_1DynamicData.html#a03e1a77369d1d5e2def6c5434bb80627), what `property` value did you pass as the second parameter?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek I know exactly what you are gonna say since I figured it out yesterday but was a little to busy to post an answer, I was doing the default properties for the 2nd argument so I then made a dynamic property object for the second property that sets to a large size such as 1mb for the max and no longer get this error.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. If you post an answer, I will upvote it ;-)

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek will do during lunch. So its not a lazy answer haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you indicated that you solved the problem. It might still be useful for others to learn about it as well, especially given that the situation depends on the Connext version that you use. Hence my answer here.

The [DynamicData()](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1dynamicdata_1_1DynamicData.html#a03e1a77369d1d5e2def6c5434bb80627) constructor for the [`com.rti.dds.dynamicdata.DynamicData`](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1dynamicdata_1_1DynamicData.html) object has a parameter called `type` of the class [`TypeCode`](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1typecode_1_1TypeCode.html) and a parameter called `property` of the class [`DynamicDataProperty_t`](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1dynamicdata_1_1DynamicDataProperty__t.html). The latter configures the behavior of the newly created object, in particular with respect to memory allocations and resource limits.

Apparently, you used the value `com.rti.dds.dynamicdata.DYNAMIC_DATA_PROPERTY_DEFAULT` as the `property` parameter. For older versions of RTI's product (before `5.2.0`), this meant that the `buffer_max_size` attribute was set to the value of 65536 bytes. This was not enough for your object, with an `RETCODE_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` exception as a result. The solution is to pass your own instantiation of the property object and set the `buffer_max_size` to a large enough value.

For the current version of the product, this is no longer required. The default value for `buffer_max_size` is now [ResourceLimitsQosPolicy.LENGTH_UNLIMITED](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/group__DDSResourceLimitsQosModule.html#gad04230e0956f0c23883cc8ba653fbf4b), indicating that there is no maximum size to the buffer.